# My system information displays that I have an amd driver installed for my gtx 1660ti for laptop

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card

Is this normal? Should the system information on Windows 10 display this?
[image]
What bothers me is that amd64 since I have a gtx1660ti for laptop.

Comment: The `amd64` refers to the fact that your cpu has the 64bit extensions as developed by AMD, and these are contained within processors build by both AMD & Intel. It is saying that the driver is 64bit, not 32bits.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`AMD64` is the official name of the [x86_64 CPU architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). AMD pioneered the 64-bit extensions to the x86 CPU that allowed us to simultaneously run both older 32 bit code at the same time as newer 64 bit code. Intel technically has their own version called EM64T but as they are essentially identical they are both referred to as the same "AMD64".

AMD64 does not mean you are using AMD drivers, but instead it is simply that your drivers are 64-bit.

You are definitely using Nvidia drivers. What you are seeing there is normal.